# How do i render animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, file-format, audio

I can not change the file to a Xvideo file which is the only movie file that seems that it would work. I have sound in my animation and already have it in the video sequencer editor. I also have sequencing turned on. It still only gives me 4 options for movie files. How can i make Xvideo an option?

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is render all the individual frames then open up a new instance of blender, and then load all of the frames you just rendered into the VSE (Video Sequence Editor). Then just choose the file type of the video, and render the animation.
See this video if you need extra clarification: https://youtu.be/5RKeDJtMT-Q

Comment: I cast a dv. From my perspective it seems, the user wants to render his animation as an "Xvideo", but only has four video formats in the dropdown menu (which don't include "Xvideo"). "*choos[ing] the file type*" seems to be the problem, could you include an answer for his actual question "*How can i make Xvideo an option?*" ?